# Cannot connect to SSAS using LAN

Tags: ssas

I cannot connect to my SSAS using excel, the error message is no such host is known.
I already set my firewall off, 
and Also I have check my listening port using netstat /abo.

But I can connect from local server.

Can you guys help me on this
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your error message means that your Operating System cannot resolve SSAS Server name into an IP address. Things I would do:

1. Specify SSAS Server IP address instead of its name in Excel, and check access. If still no access - check connectivity, ports etc.
2. If Excel connects - check for DNS server settings at your client PC with Network Admin.
   If no such person exits - go to step 1 and refer your SSAS Server with its address.